# Model of PA with false $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence but no false Con sentence?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, proof-theory

This is probably a really basic result that I'm forgetting but if $M \models \text{PA}$ and $M \models \phi$ for some $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence $\phi$ such that $\mathbb{N} \models \lnot \phi$ does it follow that there is some consistent sentence $\psi$ such that $M \models \lnot \text{Con}(\psi)$?  I vaguely feel like it ought to be possible to find a way to code up any $\Sigma^0_1$ claim as some kind of claim about consistency but I also know that this kind of intuition is very often wrong.

If yes, does the answer change if I insist that $\psi$ not only be consistent but $PA+\psi$ be consistent?  So if I'm looking at some consistent extension $T$ of PA that proves some false $\Sigma^0_1$ claim must it prove that some consistent extension of $T$ is in fact inconsistent?

(I'm kinda hoping the answer is really complex since  I feel I should know the answer but it's probably just been too long since grad school :-))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This essentially boils down to the provable  $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness of PA. Suppose $\phi$ is a $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence false in $\mathbb N$ but true in some other model $M$ of PA. Then, by $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness, $M$ also satisfies "$\phi$ is provable in PA" and therefore also satisfies $\neg\text{Con}_{PA}(\neg\phi)$. On the other hand, since  $\mathbb N$ satisfies $\neg\phi$ and all the axioms of PA, the theory PA$\,+\,\neg\phi$ is consistent and therefore the standard model satisfies $\text{Con}_{PA}(\neg\phi)$. So $\neg\phi$ can serve as the $\psi$ in your question.

Comment: But is $\Sigma_1^0$-completeness of PA itself complicated to prove?  Maybe not, I've only thought about this for a few moments so far.

Comment: @none Proving $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness in PA is not difficult but tedious and messy. It's the most complicated of the three Hilbert-Bernays derivability conditions. If I remember correctly, it's done in Shoenfield's "Mathematical Logic" (where he uses something he calls R-formulas, which amount to $\Sigma^0_1$) and probably also in Smorynski's chapter in the "Handbook of Mathematical Logic".

Comment: I think it's in Kaye too ... or at least all the pieces are though not sure about the specific claim.

Comment: @Peter: Try Peter Smith's book about Gödel's theorems.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Yah, I was just adding info in case anyone else is looking for it.  I'm certainly familiar with the $\Sigma^0_1$ completeness of PA and have references but thanks for adding some more (just clarifying in case my prior comment made it seem like I was looking)